# How to determine the exponent when using RSA

Tags: rsa, key-generation

Can someone please explain to me how, when using RSA, to determine the exponent to be used in encryption and decryption? I have attempted a worked example on using RSA (shown below) but I can't ever get the decryption algorithm to work.

Worked example:

$p  = 29$

$q  = 37$

$n  = 29*37
 = 1073$

$\phi  = (29-1)(37-1)
     = 1008$

$e = 3$

$d  = (2(1008))+1)/3
 = 672.3333333$

$m  = 121512$ (taking the positions in the alphabet for 'L', 'O' and 'L')

Encrypt:  $ c = 121512^3 \mod 1073 = 878$

Decrypt: $ 878^{672.3333333} \mod 1073 = 352.91536313837299042255202310536$

Comment: 1) You need multiply with the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) instead of dividing. 2) $\mathrm{GCD}(e, \phi) \neq 1$, so your choice of $e$ is incompatible with your choice of $q$.

Comment: Similar question [RSA Key generation: How is multiplicative inverse computed?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22490/rsa-key-generation-how-is-multiplicative-inverse-computed)

Answer (score 3):

There are three main errors here:

1. Exponent $e$ must be chosen to be **coprime** with  $\phi$. In your question, exponent $e = 3$ is not coprime with $\phi = 1008$. You can choose $e = 5$ instead.
2. You must use integer arithmetic, not floating-point. In other words, you cannot have values expressed with decimals.
3. You cannot encrypt a message bigger than the modulo (in this case, $n = 1073$).

Taking these aspects into account, the remaining steps are as follows. The private key $d$ must be computed so $e \cdot d = 1 \mod \phi$. Using [this online tool](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dsri/modular-inversion-answer.php?n=5&p=1008), we find the private key $d = 605$. Next, we cannot encipher message 121512 since is bigger than the modulo, but we can encipher the first three digits, so $m_1 = 121$. Hence, the other half of the message is $m_2 = 512$. The encryption of $m_1$ is $c_1 = (m_1)^{e} \mod n = 121^{5} \mod 1073 = 25937424601 \mod 1073 = 544$.

You can figure out the rest.

Comment: How can I do this when my values do work? Meaning, I have 128^343 (mod 480), where C = 128, d = 343, n = 480. I know with something like 128^7 I can break into (128^1, 128^2, 128^4) since 1+2+4=7. How can I do it with huge number like 343?